# my code doesnt return any string

Tags: android, jsoup

I am trying to use the jsoup to return string from a website but my code breaks after the Jsoup.connect and it doesnt return any string

my code is:

```
    class fetcher extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
 String myString = null;
 @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) { 
        Document doc = null;
        try {

            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.ismmusalla.org/").get();

            Elements divs = doc.select("div#title1");


                for (Element div : divs) {

                    myString=myString+" " +div.text();


                      }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return null;
}
 protected void onPostExecute(String result)
 {
     textview.setText(myString);


 }
}
```

Comment: But where is the `return myString` statement ?

Comment: Exactly! Where are you returning the string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your AsyncTask's `doInBackground()` has **void return type**, just change it to **String** and put `myString` instead of `null` as return `data`,

Like,

```
protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

 return myString;
}
```

Also the declaration of AsyncTask is not suitable, `extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>` it should be `extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>`.

Just look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    String myString="";
    TextView tv;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
  new TheTask().execute();

}


class TheTask extends AsyncTask <Void,Void,Void>
{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Document doc = null;
        try {

            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.ismmusalla.org/").get();

            Elements divs = doc.select("div#title1");
                for (Element div : divs) {
                    myString=myString+" " +div.text();
                      }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        tv.setText(myString);
    }

}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
     >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

snap shot of emulator

[image]

Your title 1 in html code

[image]

Or

Edit:

Return string in doInbackground and update textview in onPostExecute

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {    
TextView tv;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
  new TheTask().execute();

}

class TheTask extends AsyncTask <Void,Void,String> // change Void to String
{
    String myString="";
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) { // return type is string
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Document doc = null;
        try {

            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.ismmusalla.org/").get();

            Elements divs = doc.select("div#title1");
                for (Element div : divs) {

                    myString=myString+" " +div.text();
                      }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return myString; //return string result
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) { // recieve  string result
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        tv.setText(result); // update textview with string result
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use below code:

```
class fetcher extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{
 String myString = "";
 @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) { 
        Document doc = null;
        try {

            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.ismmusalla.org/").get();

            Elements divs = doc.select("div#title1");


                for (Element div : divs) {

                    myString=myString+" " +div.text();


                      }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return myString;
}
 protected void onPostExecute(String result)
 {
     textview.setText(result);


 }
}
```

Comment: `myString=myString+" " +div.text()' will append null also bcoz  `String myString = null`.

Comment: i changed it into myString = "" . is it oke.?